# How to make while loop with grep and variable equality work?

Tags: bash

I am trying to execute the following loop, however I'm failing. I have read about double parentheses and other things, however, I cannot manage to make it work (especially the second part in combination with `grep`). I can make each part work separately, but not both together.

First try:

```
a=1;
b=1;

while { ( n1=$(grep 'too many requests' *.htm* )) && (( $a -eq $b  )) }; do
    echo "aa"
done
```

Second try:

```
while [[  n=$(grep 'too many requests' *.htm* ) && $a==$b ]]; do
    echo "error"
done
```

Third try

```
while [[  n=$(grep 'too many requests' *.htm* ) &&  "$a" -eq "$b"  ]]; do
    echo "aa"
done
```

What I expect: if the HTML files do not contain the phrase "too many requests", and `a` is equal `b`, enter the loop.

Comment: You have an infinite loop, since you never change any of the variables during the loop.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```bash
a=1
b=1

if ! grep -q -F -- 'too many requests' *.htm* && [ "$a" = "$b" ]; then
    echo error >&2
fi
```

This uses the negated exit status of `grep` and the result of comparing `$a` and `$b` for string equality (use `[`'s `-eq` for integer evaluation of equality).  If both are *true* (the string is not found in any file matching `*.htm*` and the two variables are identical), then the `echo` is executed, outputting the string `error` to the standard error stream.

Note the use of single `=` with spaces around it. The `=` (or `-eq`) operator is an argument to the `[` (`test`) utility and not intrinsically tied to the `if` keyword.

The options `-q` and `-F` to the `grep` utility cause the utility to be quiet and to exit as soon as a match is found (`-q`) and to treat the given pattern as a text string rather than as a regular expression (`-F`).

---

Your examples use a `while` loop, which should be an `if` statement.  If you want to handle each file separately, then use a `for` loop:

```bash
for name in *.htm*; do
    if ! grep -q -F -- 'too many requests' "$name" && [ "$a" = "$b" ]
    then
        printf 'error for "%s"\n' "$name" >&2
    fi
done
```

You don't have to save the output of `grep` if you only want to test whether a pattern matches in a file or set of files.  You may instead use `grep -q` and react to the exit status of the utility, as shown above.

In your first code snippet, you use an arithmetic evaluation, `(( $a -eq $b  ))`.  This could be better written as `(( a == b ))`, which evaluates to a result that an `if` statement could use as a boolean.  The `-eq` operator is specific to the `[` utility and not valid in `(( ... ))`.

In the second code snippet, you use `$a==$b`.  This would evaluate into a string, `1==1`, which the shell would try to use as a command.

In the third code snippet, you use `"$a" -eq "$b"` within `[[ ... ]]`, which correctly performs an integer equality test between `$a` and `$b`.  This does not work as expected due to the `grep` command and the way you don't negate its exit status (and the fact that you use a `while` loop rather than an `if` statement).

Within `[ ... ]`, `=` tests for string equality and `-eq` tests for integer equality.  Technically, `==` is not a valid operator for `[ ... ]` tests, but `bash` supports it. The `bash` shell does shell pattern matching within its special `[[ ... ]]` syntax when using `==`, as in

```bash
[[ $name == *.txt ]] && echo 'The name matches *.txt'
```

Comment: So my question is grep part cannot be in parenthesis or {}[]? Right? Only outside can expression valuation happens like grep in if/while statements?

Comment: @Estatistics The way I'm using `grep` in my answer is to look at its _exit status_, which will tell me whether it found something or not. The `[ ... ]` test is done if you need to compare a string or integer to something, or when you need to test for existence of a file, or whether something is a directory or a regular file etc. (see the manual for `[` and `test`).

Comment: @Estatistics With `{ ...; }` you create a compound command. This is mostly useful if you need to fit multiple simple commands wherever only a single command is allowed, for example as a single stage in a pipeline, or to redirect several commands to the same file, as in `{ echo hello; echo world; } >outfile`.

Comment: @Estatistics The `( ... )` is a sub-shell.  This is mostly useful for creating a local temporary environment, as in `( cd dir && touch file )` (the `cd` won't affect the parent environment's working directory).  `(( ... ))` is an arithmetic evaluation, which will result in an exit status depending on the evaluation of an arithmetic expression, as in `if (( a == 0 )); then ...; fi`, or `(( a++ ))`.

Comment: Oh Very nice explanation, Now, i started to understand the use of them! Thanks!